# How to make random number with format 25-3456 and 165.09826 in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I want to create a random number with a format like that which will be used as an invoice number and also a contract number when making transactions, I use the Laravel framework

$request['no_vak'] = number_format(mt_rand(10000-9999),0,'','-');
$request['no_contract'] = number_format(mt_rand(100000,999999),0,'','-');

i want output 23-4532 and 134.93874 with random number

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FakerPHP](https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/numbers-and-strings/#regexify) for this.

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
$rand1 = $faker->regexify('[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}');
$rand2 = $faker->regexify('[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{5}');
```

Please note that you'll probably need to move FakerPHP from `require-dev` to `require` in your `composer.json` if you want to run this code in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using sprintf() Function in PHP as shown below:

```
<?php

function invoiceNumber(){
    return sprintf('%02d-%04d', mt_rand(10, 99), mt_rand(1000, 9999));
}

function contractNumber(){
    $integerPart = mt_rand(100, 999);
    $decimalPart = mt_rand(0, 999999) / 1000000;
    $contractNumber = sprintf('%03d.%06f', $integerPart, $decimalPart);
    return $contractNumber;
}

$request['no_vak'] = invoiceNumber();
$request['no_contract'] = contractNumber();

?>
```